# Slide in/out JavaFX stage from/to right side of the screen

Tags: animation, javafx-8

I have a task to make JavaFX application. When I start it the window should slides smoothly from right side of screen and when I click on "x" button it's should slides out to right side and then finishes.

I found possible to use simple Timeline animation for this. I made the window to slide in, when I run app, but can't figure out how to slide out window.

I tried to handle this defining handler via setOnCloseRequest() method of stage, but stuck with two problems:

1. can't implement animation
2. after click on "x" application closed immediately even if I use consume() method of Window event

Code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Main");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);


        Rectangle2D primScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        stage.setX(primScreenBounds.getMinX() + primScreenBounds.getWidth());
        System.out.println(primScreenBounds.getWidth());
        stage.setY(primScreenBounds.getMinY());
        stage.setWidth(0);
        stage.setHeight(primScreenBounds.getHeight());

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.setAutoReverse(true);

        WritableValue<Double> writableWidth = new WritableValue<Double>() {
            @Override
            public Double getValue() {
                return stage.getWidth();
            }

            @Override
            public void setValue(Double value) {
                stage.setWidth(value);
            }
        };

        KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(writableWidth, 600d);
        KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), kv);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(kf);
        timeline.play();
        stage.show();
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                event.consume();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works (kind of, it is not very smooth) for me:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.WritableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SlidingWindow extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setTitle("Main");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);


        Rectangle2D primScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        double screenRightEdge = primScreenBounds.getMaxX() ;
        stage.setX(screenRightEdge);
        System.out.println(primScreenBounds.getWidth());
        stage.setY(primScreenBounds.getMinY());
        stage.setWidth(0);
        stage.setHeight(primScreenBounds.getHeight());

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();


        WritableValue<Double> writableWidth = new WritableValue<Double>() {
            @Override
            public Double getValue() {
                return stage.getWidth();
            }

            @Override
            public void setValue(Double value) {
                stage.setX(screenRightEdge - value);
                stage.setWidth(value);
            }
        };


        KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(writableWidth, 600d);
        KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), kv);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(kf);
        timeline.play();
        stage.show();
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
                KeyFrame endFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), new KeyValue(writableWidth, 0.0));
                timeline.getKeyFrames().add(endFrame);
                timeline.setOnFinished(e -> Platform.runLater(() -> stage.hide()));
                timeline.play();
                event.consume();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The `Platform.runLater(...)` seems necessary to prevent a slew of `NullPointerException`s when the window is hidden, probably because the animation is causing some system to try to access a stage that no longer exists.

Comment: Thank you! It's works, but not in the way that I expect. I did some experiments with setting width to 0 but I need that after closing window moves in direction from which it appears. And now it's moving left. I have no idea is it possible to do it in that way.

Comment: Please explain. It appears from the left to the right, and closes back to the left (i.e. the direction from which it appears). What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that when I click on close window should move to the right and then disappear.

Comment: I would consider that as shrinking to the opposite direction to the direction from which it came. You can update the window's `x` property when the `width` changes, but it gets (even more) flicker... See update.

Comment: Thank you! Yes. This is exactly what I need. Is it possible make it less flicker?

Comment: It's difficult to eliminate that flicker, because there's no way to ensure the system doesn't respond to the changes in width and x independently. See update; that works a little more cleanly for me...

Comment: OK. Thank you for help!